# UITableView With three section and three cell

Tags: ios, swift

I am using Three section and Three Cell like,
Section 1 cell 1
section 1 cell 2
section 1 cell 3

Section 2 cell 1
Section 2 cell 2
Section 2 cell 3

Section 3 cell 1
Section 3 cell 2
Section 3 cell 3

But i am trying to customize with following figure

Section 1 cell 1
     --- This section for displaying user profile
section 2 cell 1
     -- This section showing multiple images
section 3 cell 1
     -- This section for comments related to images

Section 1 cell 2
     --- This section for displaying user profile
Section 2 cell 2
     -- This section showing multiple images
Section 3 cell 2
     -- This section for comments related to images

.
.
.
.
Section 1 cell 3
Section 2 cell 3
Section 3 cell 3

can any one help me to solving this with code

Comment: Sorry, but your figure isn't showing up.

Comment: i have already defined dynamic cell and prototype cell

Comment: In that case you'll have to define cellForRowAtIndexPath and use tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier to instantiate your cells. Please see the "Prototype Cells" section in the tutorial I posted in my answer bellow.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest starting with a storyboard.. Are these cells always going to be the same no matter what (use static cells in the storyboard for your UIView), or are you planning on adding cells programmatically (use dynamic cells and define a prototype cell).

The following is an excellent tutorial on stroyboards that should help get you started:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/81879/storyboards-tutorial-swift-part-1